# Where and what is conf.ps? Asked when I input the command ps

Tags: macos, command, ps

When I write ps on the command line (mac) I get
config file [conf.ps] not found

Any ideas on what this conf.ps is or why suddenly ps is not working?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it changing the Terminfo in Terminal's preferences from xterm-256color to ansi.
It seems the xterm-256color type looks for that conf.ps file which I was missing.